# How to pass parameter for dynamic route?

Tags: vue.js, routes, vuex, vue-router

I need on click go to the next page which is created with a dynamic route. It gets the id for the route from a vuex store. When I'm clicking it gives this url

```
http://localhost:8080/worklist/%7Bname:'worklistDynamic',%20params:%7B%20id:sideSwiperItems[indx+1].id%7D%7D
 ---------------------------------------
```

here is my code:

```
//html
.side-button-next(@click='switchPage()')
//function
--------------------------
switchPage() {
      this.$router.push(
        `{name:'worklistDynamic', params:{ id:this.sideSwiperItems[this.indx+1].id}}`,
      )
    },
--------------------------
computed: {
sideSwiperItems() {
  return this.$store.state.buildingData.sideSwiperItems
},
indx() {
  if (this.$store.state.buildingData.index === null) {
    return 0
  }
  return this.$store.state.buildingData.index
},
```

},

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the backticks:

```js
switchPage() {
  let path = { name: 'worklistDynamic', params: { id: this.sideSwiperItems[this.indx + 1].id } }

  // or you can write the full path with backticks and interpolation
  let path = `/worklistDynamic/${this.sideSwiperItems[this.indx + 1].id}`

  this.$router.push(path)
}
```